# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.を解決したいです

Tags: python

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.を解決したいです．
下記にコードを記載させていただきました．

調べてみたところ配列の次元数が違うと出ます．その意味は分かるのですが，なぜそのエラーが出ているのかわかりません．

このエラーを解決するためにはどの部分を修正したらいいのでしょうか．
ご教授いただけますと幸いです．

```
from facenet_pytorch import MTCNN, InceptionResnetV1
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

data_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/研究/試作/data/"

img_num = 44

mtcnn = MTCNN(image_size=160, margin=10)
 

resnet = InceptionResnetV1(pretrained='vggface2').eval()

img_da = np.zeros((img_num, 512))

for num in range(img_num):
    
    img = Image.open(data_path+'criterion/images'+str(num)+'.jpg')  
    
    img_cropped = mtcnn(img)
    
    img_cropped = mtcnn(img, save_path=data_path+'cropped/pcropped_img'+str(num)+'.jpg')

    
    img_embedding = resnet(img_cropped.unsqueeze(0))
 
    img_da[num] = img_embedding.squeeze().to('cpu').detach().numpy().copy()

np.savetxt(data_path+'data.txt', img_da)

criterion_data = np.loadtxt(data_path+'data.txt')
# print(criterion_data)


def cos_similarity(p1, p2): 
    return np.dot(p1, p2) / (np.linalg.norm(p1) * np.linalg.norm(p2))


visi_a = np.zeros((img_num, criterion_data.shape[0]))
# visi_a
# array_info(visi_a)
for num in range(img_num):

    img = Image.open(data_path+'visitor/images'+str(num)+'.jpg')  

    #img_cropped = mtcnn(img)

    img_cropped = mtcnn(img, save_path=data_path+"cropped/cropped_img"+str(num)+".jpg")


    img_embedding = resnet(img_cropped.unsqueeze(0))

    img_a = img_embedding.squeeze().to('cpu').detach().numpy().copy()

    for numd in range(criterion_data.shape[0]):
        visi_a[num][numd] = cos_similarity(img_a, criterion_data[numd])
    #print(visi_a[num])

np.savetxt(data_path+'visitor_data.txt', visi_a)
```

コメントありがとうございます．
下記にエラー内容を追記させていただきます．

モジュールはGoogle colaboを使用しました．
画像等はインターネットからランダムな人の画像を取得し，使用しました．

```
100%
107M/107M [00:28<00:00, 9.13MB/s]
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:780: UserWarning: Note that order of the arguments: ceil_mode and return_indices will changeto match the args list in nn.MaxPool2d in a future release.
  warnings.warn("Note that order of the arguments: ceil_mode and return_indices will change"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-257eaee68c36> in <module>()
     59     # 新しい訪問者が来たときには，このデータと比較して類似している人であるという判定をする
     60     for numd in range(criterion_data.shape[0]):
---> 61         visi_a[num][numd] = cos_similarity(img_a, criterion_data[numd])
     62     #print(visi_a[num])
     63 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: エラーメッセージの全文もテキストで記述してください。それから使用したモジュールやデータ等はどこからどう入手したのか、公開されていない場合は代替手段等があればそれも記述(無いなら他の人が再現・調査出来るように内容を変更)してください。

Comment: 「このエラーを解決するためにはどの部分を修正したらいいのでしょうか．」とありますが、エラー発生元（行）は何処でしょうか？画像ファイルはカラーですか？モノクロですか？

Comment: 手元の適当な画像で試したところエラーは発生しませんでした。